# timebase denominator exceeds H.264 maximum

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, edit-mode

I am trying to do some video editing in Blender. I can render using AVI format, the problem appears when I am using ffmpeg.

The steps I am following:

- [Video Sequence Editor] Add->movie [...I select a video to import]
- [Properties] Output -> FFmpeg video, Encoding -> presets -> h264 in MP4
- [Info] Render-> Render Animation

The rendering immediately stops and shows an error:

`Effective timebase denominator 3276700000 exceeds H.264 maximum`

What am I doing so wrong? The process does just fine if I use AVI but I need to output mp4 for a school project.

Comment: No it is a mobile phone video. Anyway I resolved using the animation button in properties and not info->animation

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve this problem was changing the frame rate to the device I was recording at. once I did this it started rendering the animation. (Before it was at 30 fps and I changed it to 29.97.) I hope this helped